# How can I export a list of databases resident on a given Domino server?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a Lotus Domino server with a truly astounding number of Domino databases on it, arranged in various folders.

Is there some means of exporting a list of all these databases, with their titles and creators' names, in a spreadsheet format of some kind? I have the Domino Admin and Domino Designer software, and I have or can get whatever access rights I'd need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd think there'd be a way in the Domino Admin, but there's no way to export the list.  So, your best bet I think is to use the Domain Catalog database.  To build it, go into the server configuration doc > Server Tasks > and turn on the Domain Catalog.  Then the catalog.nsf database will be built and will contain all the databases in your domain.  You can customize the views to include the information you need.

Then finally, you can go into a view, select all the documents and click Edit > Copy Selected As Table.  Then paste that into a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you can use a very simple Lotuscript agent to connect to a server and walk through all databases on the server, using the NotesDbDirectory class. Here is some code, modified slightly from what's in the 6.5 Help files - this dumps the title and path of all databases to a csv file. Note: the one argument to the GetFirstDatabase method let's you specify which objects on the server you want to scan - 1247 is the constant for "Databases" - basically, all NSF files. There are other constants for finding templates only (NTF's), only database with replication enabled, etc.

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim f As Integer
    f = Freefile
    Open "c:\dbExport.csv" For Output As #f

    Dim dbdir As New NotesDbDirectory("")  ' opens LOCAL - put a server name here
    Set db = dbdir.GetFirstDatabase(1247)  ' all databases - NSF, NSG and NSH (no templates)
    While Not(db Is Nothing)
        Print #f, """" + db.Title + """, """ + db.FileName + """"
        Set db = dbdir.GetNextDatabase
    Wend
    Close #f
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a little known fact that you can "select all" in the Admin client and paste into Excel. There is also an option for a flat view of databases instead of a folder view.

The creator of the database is not listed but there is a lot of other useful information

Answer (score 1):

Inherited some legacy server, didn't we ?

If the server was sensibly maintained in the past, you already have the following things :

- a catalog.nsf database, which is exactly what you want, only better
- the `catalog` server task up and running.

The catalog task is the task that automatically builds and maintain the catalog.nsf database. If it is not already running, you can launch it once at teh server console in Domino admin :
    `load catalog`

and even better, add it to the server tasks in the server's notes.ini

Now, the catalog tasks only cover the databases whose properties have been set such as to allow cataloging. A well behaved Domino admin would not allow a database to reach production without those properties properly set (and I believe it is the default anyway) but it seems you are not exactly in a nominal situation.

If this is not enough *and* if you have time to tinker around, I was in a similar situation once, and I built a database with some rather advanced scripts to conduct a thourough census, including agents and their schedules etc. If you want, I'd be happy to pass it to you.

Have fun with your new toy !