# Lotus notes: find all private views

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In my notes log sometimes i find `V_CRRPT_` views and i want to delete it.

Is there a method to find all private view on my domino server ?

*I tried to find it by switching .id files for every user but is an operation that requires to much time.*

**There is a section in domino administrator or terminal command to search all private view and delete it ?**

thank's

Comment: I never use private views. It seems like that is something new/beginner Notes developers are very fond of for some reason. They are not aware of all the issues with private views, they just go for the solution they think is the easiest at the moment, and one where they are not required to think though the problem and actually solve it...
I highly recommend not to use private views, it is very rare you actually need them, if you design your application correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read [Private views how to get them](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Private-views-how-to-get-them) ?

The idea is to search PER DB (it could be a lot of job if you have a lot of Notes DBs).

now if you want to "do it your self", look at *isPrivate* :

```
import lotus.domino.*;
import java.util.Vector;
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
public void NotesMain() {
try {
  Session session = getSession();
  AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
  // (Your code goes here) 
  Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
  Vector views = db.getViews();
  for (int i=0; i<views.size(); i++) {
    View view = (View)views.elementAt(i);
    if (view.isPrivate())
      System.out.println("View is private");
    else
      System.out.println("View is shared");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

You will have to loop for all DBs on the server: [How can I export a list of databases resident on a given Domino server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284821/how-can-i-export-a-list-of-databases-resident-on-a-given-domino-server)